# python configparser writes configuration file to one line

Tags: python, configparser

I have a configuration file that I would like to change settings to from a python script. Here is my skeleton code:

```
config = ConfigParser()        
config.read('settings.conf')
config.set("SCRIPT", "SOMEFIELD", "%s"%SOMEVALUE)
config.write(open("settings.conf","wb"))
```

This works fine, however it writes everything to one line. I might be being a bit picky, but would like to have new lines after each configurations field and section so that the file is human readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are telling python to write a binary file ("b" char on 2nd arg of your open() call).

Use

```
config.write(open("settings.conf","w"))
```

Or better:

```
with open("settings.conf","w") as settings_file:
    config.write(settings_file)
```